# map array of objects to table in react without using name of the key names

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array and I would like to render this array with  without using keys because keys will not be the same every time. Even the number of keys in the next array will not be same. I have tried using map function but could not achieve success with key names.

```
const array1 = [{"BRANCH":"84","NUM":"1356","COST":"25","METHOD":"15"},
{"BRANCH":"3","NUM":"2134", "COST":"425","METHOD":"5"},
{"BRANCH":"4","NUM":"1905","COST":"325","METHOD":"1"},
{"BRANCH":"56","NUM":"2350","COST":"14", "METHOD":"9"}] 

const array2 = [{"UNIT":"84", "COST":"25"},
{"UNIT":"3","COST":"425"},
{"UNIT":"4","COST":"325"},
{"UNIT":"56","COST":"14"}]
```

Please suggest me map function to iterate over this array to render into Table. Thanks

Comment: In this example, all your keys are the same

Comment: could you please post the proper format of array object this is incomplete.

Comment: @mah111 i have added array2. each time the number of keys may not be the same.

Comment: can you post a sample table output that you would like to render? May be a sample image

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

***NOTE: this is just a sample code please try to create your own logic for better results:***

```
const array1 = [
  { BRANCH: "84", NUM: "1356", COST: "25", METHOD: "15" },
  { BRANCH: "3", NUM: "2134", COST: "425", METHOD: "5" },
  { BRANCH: "4", NUM: "1905", COST: "325", METHOD: "1" },
  { BRANCH: "56", NUM: "2350", COST: "14", METHOD: "9" }
];

const array2 = [{"UNIT":"84", "COST":"25"},
{"UNIT":"3","COST":"425"},
{"UNIT":"4","COST":"325"},
{"UNIT":"56","COST":"14"}]

const Table = ({item}) => {
    const items = Object.entries(item);
    return (
      <td>
        {
          items.map(([key,value]) => {
           return (
              <tr key={value}>{value}</tr>
             )
          })
        }
       </td>
    )
}

const createTable = ({arr}) => {
  return (
    arr.map(item => {
      return <Table {...item} />
    })
  )
};


<CreateTable arr={array1} />
<CreateTable arr={array2} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure what do you want. I'm guessing you want to use index as keys while using the map method?

```js
const arr = [{"BRANCH":"3","NUM":"2134", "COST":"425","METHOD":"5"},
{"BRANCH":"4","NUM":"1905","COST":"325","METHOD":"1"},
{"BRANCH":"56","NUM":"2350","COST":"14", "METHOD":"9"}] 

const arrMap = arr.map((el,index) => {
  return [{key:index, ...el}]
})

console.log(arrMap)
// [
//   [ { key: 0, BRANCH: '3', NUM: '2134', COST: '425', METHOD: '5' } ],
//   [ { key: 1, BRANCH: '4', NUM: '1905', COST: '325', METHOD: '1' } ],
//   [ { key: 2, BRANCH: '56', NUM: '2350', COST: '14', METHOD: '9' } ]
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
  const array1 = [
    { BRANCH: "3", NUM: "2134", COST: "425", METHOD: "5" },
    { BRANCH: "4", NUM: "1905", COST: "325", METHOD: "1" },
    { BRANCH: "56", NUM: "2350", COST: "14", METHOD: "9" }
  ];

  const array2 = [
    { UNIT: "84", COST: "25" },
    { UNIT: "3", COST: "425" },
    { UNIT: "4", COST: "325" },
    { UNIT: "56", COST: "14" }
  ];

  const tempFunc = (arrayItem) => {
    const obj = Object.keys(arrayItem);
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      const name = obj[i];
      const value = arrayItem[name];

      console.log("name:", name, " value:", value);
    }
  };

  array1.map((item) => tempFunc(item));
  array2.map((item) => tempFunc(item));
```